# Cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const wchar_t *' to 'LPCTSTR' in MFC / C++ project

Tags: c++, string, mfc, tchar, lpcwstr

I get a compilation error on the line:

```
 MessageBox(e.getAllExceptionStr().c_str(), _T("Error initializing the sound player"));

Error   4   error C2664: 'CWnd::MessageBoxA' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const wchar_t *' to 'LPCTSTR'   c:\users\daniel\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\mytest1\mytest1\main1.cpp 141 1   MyTest1
```

I don't know how to resolve this error, I tried the following:

```
MessageBox((wchar_t *)(e.getAllExceptionStr().c_str()), _T("Error initializing the sound player"));
MessageBox(_T(e.getAllExceptionStr().c_str()), _T("Error initializing the sound player"));
```

I am using the setting "Use Multi-Byte Character Set" and I don't want to change it.

Comment: I'm not sure why `getAllExceptionStr` returns a wide string if you're stuck with ANSI, but then you'll have to *convert* (note: not cast) it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is simply to use `MessageBoxW` instead of `MessageBox`.

```
MessageBoxW(e.getAllExceptionStr().c_str(), L"Error initializing the sound player");
```

The second easiest way is to create a new CString from the original; it will automatically convert to/from wide string and MBCS string as necessary.

```
CString msg = e.getAllExceptionStr().c_str();
MessageBox(msg, _T("Error initializing the sound player"));
```

Comment: I think if the purpose of the conversion is to just pass the string as a temporary to some function/method like `MessageBox()` in the above case, using `CW2T` for the conversion is more efficient than creating a new `CString` instance. `CString` has more features than `CW2T`, but also **more overhead**. Moreover, `CW2T` and the other ATL conversion helpers also implement an optimization for "small" strings, with a _stack-allocated buffer_ for small strings, instead of allocating memory from the heap.

Comment: @Mr.C64 I'm sure you're right, but I think worrying about overhead in a call to MessageBox could be the poster child for *premature optimization*.

Comment: Everyone is free to write the code he likes. I prefer using the aforementioned helpers when there are strings to be converted as parameters to functions/methods (including MessageBox): to me that is higher quality code than using CString in that context. Everyone has his own programming style. I think it's better to use high-quality style independently if you call foo(), bar() or MessageBox().

Answer (score 1):

`LPCSTR = const char*`. You are passing it a `const wchar*`, which clearly is not the same thing.

Always check that you are passing API functions the right parameters. `_T("")` type C-string are wide strings and can't be used with that version of `MessageBox()`.

Answer (score 1):

As `e.getAllExceptionStr().c_str()` is returning wide string then the following will work:

`MessageBoxW(e.getAllExceptionStr().c_str(), L"Error initializing the sound player");`

Note the `W` on the end of `MessageBoxW`;

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compile in the obsolete MBCS mode, you may want to use the [ATL/MFC string conversion helpers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3.aspx), like **`CW2T`**, e.g.:

```
MessageBox(
    CW2T(e.getAllExceptionStr().c_str()),
    _T("Error initializing the sound player")
);
```

It seems that your `getAllExceptionStr()` method returns a `std::wstring`, so calling `.c_str()` on it returns a `const wchar_t*`.

`CW2T` converts from `wchar_t`-string to `TCHAR`-string, which in your case (considering the MBCS compilation mode), is equivalent to `char`-string.

Note however that conversions from Unicode (`wchar_t`-strings) to MBCS (`char`-strings) can be lossy.